How to clean up a std::vector<int*> without memory leaks reported by _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()
I've encountered a problem which is I can't correctly deallocate memory. I have a vector of type int* and
after allocating memory and adding these pointers to my vector, I just want to deallocate the memory and end the program.
std::vector<int*> students;
students.push_back(new int);
students.push_back(new int);
students.push_back(new int);
students.push_back(new int);
students.push_back(new int);
students.push_back(new int);
students.push_back(new int);
for (const auto& student : students) {
    delete student;
}
students.clear();
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();

But, I get the following output from my visual studio 2022:
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{170} normal block at 0x000001C4AAE05BF0, 72 bytes long.
 Data: <#       #       > 23 81 00 00 00 00 00 00 23 81 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{157} normal block at 0x000001C4AAE11E80, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <  u:            > C8 F5 75 3A AF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.

I just don't understand. First, I faced this problem with more complicated project than this (project comprised of classes and other stuff) and i thought maybe the problem with memory leaks was somewhere in destructors or idk, but.. idk...
p.s. to detect memory leaks I use crtdbg.h
Help me correctly deallocate memory please

The vector is realsing its internal memory in the destructor which is only called when it gets out of scope. Move the test code into a separate function and you'll see no leaks report.

A side note: why do you need int* elements ? Why no simply ints ?

std::vector.clear() "Leaves the capacity() of the vector unchanged", i.e. it doesn't release the memory the vector has allocated to accommodate potential elements. Aside: a vector of raw owning pointers to dynamically allocated objects would generally be seen as a bad idea.

The only way to be absolutely sure that a vector has released all its memory is to ensure that it's destructor has been invoked. Your code does not do that.

int* is often bigger than int and I'm not sure why you do that to vector. Even if you need a pointer later, raw pointers are Bad Idea here

Use students.clear(); students.shrink_to_fit(); or std::vector<int*>().swap(students);

I assume your vector test code is written in the same function where you call _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() at the end (and without an inner scope using { ... }).
The vector is guaranteed to release its internal memory only in the destructor, which is invoked in your case only when it gets out of scope. But the call to _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() is made before that is done, and hence it reports the leaks.
You can make sure the vector goes out of scope by moving the test code to a separate function, and you'll observe no leak:
#include <vector>

void test()
{
    std::vector<int*> students;
    students.push_back(new int);
    students.push_back(new int);
    students.push_back(new int);
    // ...
    for (const auto& student : students) {
        delete student;
    }
    students.clear(); 
} // here the vector's destructor will be called and release the internal momory

int main() {
    test();
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}

Note that the call to students.clear() is not really needed in this case, as the destructor will take care of everything related to reasource cleanup.
A side note: apart from educational purposes, it's not a good practice to store int* in the vector. Store either ints, or std::optional<int> if you want to keep the "null"/empty option.

This whole code that i posted is in the main() function

That's what I assumed. Move it to a separate fucntion as I showed above and you'll see the reported leak gone.

it's should pair  of _CrtMemCheckPoint  with  _CrtMemDifference and _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); from MS debug CRT library, not sure why OP's snippet is missing closing state

@Swift-FridayPie not sure, but anyway I managed to reproduce the memory leak report with only calling _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks.

hmm.. I guess it just dumps everything allocated by program in that case.. which includes global objects which aren't part of CRT

@Swift-FridayPie afaik it has some magic to not count globals from the standard library, like eg std::cout etc.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai these ARE CRT. CRT is MS andalog of Linux libc. These functions are part of debug version of it (along with some exported entry points and hooks). Afaik magic consists at calling certain checkpoint at end of initialization of these globals.

@Swift-FridayPie ah ok. Thanks for clarification. All I know about _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() is from SO questions, so there are some holes in my knowledge ;)

@463035818_is_not_an_ai they have a good online reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/debug-routines?view=msvc-170 and CodeProject had quuite a number of snippets. The checkpoints are useful if you look for leak in certain unit of if it causes allocation side-effects.

_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); cannot see into the future. It will still see the vector itself that is still in scope. Note that std::vector::clear leaves the capacity of the vector unchanged. Hence, the "leak" you see is the memory allocated by the vector.
In some sense, what is a "memory leak" and what is none is up to interpretation. Sometimes you do want something to "leak" out of a scope. Consider a factory function that internally allocates some object and returns a (smart) pointer to it. The factory itself will not delete the object, it "leaks" it to the outside. The scope you do not want something to leak out of is main, or some other function where due to the logic of your code you know that the function will clean up anything it allocated (a tool cannot know that).
A different, more narrow interpretation is that a "leak" is when you allocated something and you do not have any pointer or reference to the allocated resource any more, hence no way to clean it up even if you wanted to. That's a sure leak. However, this notion is too narrow, because it does not cover the cases where you still have a pointer/reference but still forget to clean up (and even smart pointers cannot completely eliminate those).
Change your code to:
int main() {
    {
        // ... do it all here ...
    } // <- does something leak this scope ?
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}

The tool merely detects if some memory is still allocated. Only you know that at the point where you measure everything should have been cleaned up already.
